# Error when pretraining using spacy 3.0. What exactly is the raw_text?

Tags: nlp, spacy-3

Pretraining custom weights in Spacy pipeline gives error.

When I run this using a jupyter notebook:

`!python -m spacy pretrain config.cfg ./output_pretrain --paths.raw_text ./data.jsonl`

The following error occurs:

```
[i] Using CPU
[i] Loading config from: config.cfg
[x] Error parsing config overrides
paths -> raw_text   not a section value that can be overwritten
```

### My Environment

- Operating System: Windows 10.0.19041
- Python Version Used: 3.8.8
- spaCy Version Used:3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

The way the [`spacy pretrain`](https://spacy.io/api/cli#pretrain) command works is like this: you provide it a [config](https://spacy.io/api/data-formats#config) file, and an output directory. Optionally, you can override certain settings from the config file on the command line. For instance, if your config file would contain this block:

```
[paths]
train = null
dev = null
raw_text = "path/to/toy_data"
```

Then on the command line you can do `--raw_text="path/to/production_data"` to change that one specific value.

Now, it looks like you're getting this error message because you don't have an entry `raw_text` in the `paths` block, so you can't overwrite it.

In fact, I wonder whether you have defined a `pretraining` block in your config file?
If not - have a look at [`spacy init config`](https://spacy.io/api/cli#init-config). You can provide it with the option `-pt` which will fill in default values for the [pretraining step](https://spacy.io/usage/embeddings-transformers#pretraining), specifically it will create something like this (among the other 'normal' settings):

```
[paths]
raw_text = null
...

[pretraining]
max_epochs = 1000
dropout = 0.2
n_save_every = null
component = "tok2vec"
layer = ""
corpus = "corpora.pretrain"

[pretraining.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_words.v1"
size = 3000
discard_oversize = false
tolerance = 0.2
get_length = null

[pretraining.objective]
@architectures = "spacy.PretrainCharacters.v1"
maxout_pieces = 3
hidden_size = 300
n_characters = 4

[pretraining.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
L2_is_weight_decay = true
L2 = 0.01
grad_clip = 1.0
use_averages = true
eps = 0.00000001
learn_rate = 0.001
...

[corpora.pretrain]
@readers = "spacy.JsonlCorpus.v1"
path = ${paths.raw_text}
min_length = 5
max_length = 500
limit = 0
```

Notice how the `raw_text` variable is used by a corpus reader, that will stream the raw text for your pretraining step. So you need to make sure all of this is wired up correctly before you can run the pretraining.